# The AppBarDesign can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone please give some information why this is happening?

When I try to add a class **AppBarDesign** which implements **appBar** flutter is giving the below error.

> error: The argument type 'AppBarDesign' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [flutterbyrajath] lib\main.dart:27)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    main() {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Rajath\'s design ',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
          home: new MyHomePage(key, 'App is Fun'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      MyHomePage(Key key, this.title) : super(key: key);

      final title;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBarDesign(key, title),
        );
      }
    }

    class AppBarDesign extends StatelessWidget {
      AppBarDesign(Key key, this.title) : super(key: key);

      final title;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new AppBar(
          title: new Text(title),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: When I add appBar : appBar(); it is working well. It only throws the error when I add a class to it.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Scaffold requires as appbar a class that implements [PreferredSizeWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html)

Either wrap your custom appbar into a [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html)

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
    child: Container(color: Colors.red),
  ),
)
```

or implement [PreferredSizeWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html):

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),
)

...

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 223):

Helpful tips to implement that without searching any other topics:

```
class ApplicationToolbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar( ... );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Please note: if you didn't update to Dart 3, you can use 'with' instead of 'implements'

```
class ApplicationToolbar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{...]
```

Comment: Both with and implements can be used `class ApplicationToolbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget{ ...
}`

Comment: From where does it get the `preferredSize ` property value?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew from this : `Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)`

Comment: To use with `TabBar`: `const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + kTextTabBarHeight);`

Comment: In Dart 3.0.0 and Flutter 3.1.0 this not works as expected - in others versions are ok. Any ideas to follow this strategy? Because I think that this is the best way to follow, is more elegant.

Comment: @FelipeSales updated to Flutter >3

Comment: @DolDurma perfect, that's what I did.

Answer (score 8):

First:
implement your class

```
implements PreferredSizeWidget
```

Second:
Enter Height

```
@override
Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(AppBar().preferredSize.height);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Create this class:

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  @override
  final Widget child;
  final double height;

  CustomAppBar({
    required this.height,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(child: child, preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(height));
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
appBar: CustomAppBar(
  height: 100,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('0'),
        Text('1'),
        Text('2'),
        Text('3'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ever since they added `null safety` this is throwing up all sorts of error! :(

Comment: @Anoop.P.A Updated the code to null-safety.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use following way to design your appbar in separate file and then use it in your whole app.

```
Widget Custom_Appbar(){
  return AppBar(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20))),
        title: Text(
          'Decimal to Binary & Vice Versa',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 19),
        ));
}
```

And then use it like this

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: Custom_Appbar(),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get the error

> The argument type x can't be assigned to the parameter type
>   'PreferredSizeWidget'.

Just wrap x in the PreferredSize widget.

Example:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    new Tab(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Here I get the error: The argument type 'Column' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.

Solution:

Click on Column

Click on light bulb

Choose Wrap with Widget

Replace widget with PreferredSize

Add a PreferredSize attribute, such as preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),

Result:

```
appBar: AppBar(
     bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                      new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                      new Tab(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```