# Changing the AppBar colour when a new tab is selected (Flutter)

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I have an app with a tab bar and to make the UI better, I wanted to make it so that the colour changes when you got to another tab. How do I make it so that when I click or swipe to another tab, let's say the yellow tab, the whole appbar changes to that colour?

[image]

Code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ColorChange>(
      create: (context) => ColorChange(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        home: SimpleTab(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
TabController controller;

class ColorChange extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color color = colors[0];

  Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  void changeColor() {
    color = colors[controller.index];
    print(color);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

List<Color> colors = const [
  Colors.green,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.deepOrange,
  Colors.deepPurple,
];

class SimpleTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleTabState createState() => _SimpleTabState();
}

class _SimpleTabState extends State<SimpleTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Tester tester = Tester();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: colors.length, vsync: this);
    controller.addListener(ColorChange().changeColor);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Tab Demo"),
        backgroundColor: Provider.of<ColorChange>(context).getColor(),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'Green',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Yellow',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Red',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Blue',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Orange',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Purple',
            ),
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
          Container(
//            child: WidgetThing(tester: tester),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is just a very simplified demo of my real app. My real app deals with a lot of data fetched from APIs, hence it is probably better if setstate() was not used, because re-building the whole widget may call http requests unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo App',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: SimpleTab(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTab {
  const CustomTab({this.title, this.color});

  final String title;
  final Color color;
}

class SimpleTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleTabState createState() => _SimpleTabState();
}

class _SimpleTabState extends State<SimpleTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  List<CustomTab> tabs = const <CustomTab>[
    const CustomTab(title: 'Home', color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
    const CustomTab(title: 'Setting', color: Colors.blueGrey),
    const CustomTab(title: 'Map', color: Colors.teal),
  ];

  CustomTab selectedTab;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);
    controller.addListener(_select);
    selectedTab = tabs[0];
  }

  void _select() {
    setState(() {
      selectedTab = tabs[controller.index];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    textStyle() {
      return new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0);
    }

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Smiple Tab Demo"),
        backgroundColor: selectedTab.color,
        bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            tabs: tabs
                .map((e) => new Tab(
                      text: e.title,
                    ))
                .toList()),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: tabs
              .map(
                (e) => new Container(
                  color: e.color,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text(
                      e.title,
                      style: textStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution, but do you know how to change the colour using provider? Because I don't want to re-build the whole widget every time I go to another tab.

Comment: You need to wrap the `AppBar` widget by `ChangeNotifierProvider` or `Consumer` and notify the change.

Comment: Please mark and upvote the answer if you find it useful

Comment: Sorry, can you show me how that can be done in the code above?

Comment: You can create one `notifier` for it. Check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: Hi! I have edited my code above to use ChangeNotifierProvider to change the colour of the app bar, but it is not changing. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: `backgroundColor: Provider.of<ColorChange>(context).getColor()` won't be called when the value changes. You need to wrap the whole `AppBar` as I told you earlier.

Comment: I get error: "The argument type 'ChangeNotifierProvider<ChengeNotifier> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget' "

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678469/the-appbardesign-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-preferredsizewidget)