# Change AppBar back icon size in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

Here's the current **`AppBar`** code:

```
AppBar(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.black,
    size: 100 // This isn't performing any changes
  ),
  centerTitle: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  title: Text(
    title,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,

  ),
  elevation: 1.0,
);
```

Current size attribute from **`IconThemeData`** not making any change.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508257/how-to-change-the-appbar-back-button-color?

Comment: No, that one is for color changing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this you need to use [`leading`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html)

- A widget to display before the title.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 AppBar(
      title: new Text("Your Title"),
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back,size: 50.0,),
        onPressed: () => {
          // Perform Your action here
        },
      ),
    );
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Transform.scale` widget and wrap `IconButton` with it. This widget has `scale` property which you can set based on your need. Working sample code below:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Transform.scale(
          scale: 2,
          child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {}
          )
        ),

  centerTitle: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  title: Text(
    'test',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,

  ),
//  elevation: 1.0,
)),
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.